# how to call a static member function inside a cpp file

Tags: c++, static-methods

I'm wondering if I can call a static member function inside a cpp file like the following:

**A.h**

```
class A
{
public:
A(){}
virtual ~A(){}

static void Initialize(){ g_pSomeType = new SomeType();}

private:
static SomeType* g_pSomeType;
};
```

**A.cpp**

```
#include "A.h"

SomeType* A::g_pSomeType = nullptr;

A::Initialize(); //here I get an error: "Initialize may not be redeclared outside of it's class"
```

Is it possible to do something like this? So that I would be able to initialize the static members inside the .cpp file of the class, to avoid users from having to call initialize() first? I suppose I could find a way to work around this problem but I'm curious if there's a way to let this work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot write any executable code outside a function body. You can only call `A::Initialize()` (or do any other function/method call) only if you're inside a function or a method...

The compiler thinks that you're **declaring** `A::Initialize()` again rather than calling it.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `initialize()` from the constructor (perhaps if it has not been called before).

Comment: Well, the problem is, in reality my class A is inherited from class B.
Class B's constructor is something like B(SomeType* pSomeType);
So A's constructor should call B's constructor, with the g_pSomeType already pointing to the allocated object. So I have to allocate the object before the call to B's constructor, and that's not possible?